# Big M on convex optimization

Tags: convex-optimization, mathematical-modeling, operations-research

Given the following convex optimization problem

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rl}
F(x):= \min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}\ &x^{T}Ax+b^{T}x\\
\text{s.t.}\ & |x| \leq M  \quad (i.e., |x_1| \leq M, |x_2| \leq M, \dots, |x_m|\leq M)
\end{array}
\end{equation}

where $A$ is a symmetric positive-definite matrix and $M$ is a large number ensuring a valid upper bound for each $x_i$.

Suppose we replace the constraint with the following

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rl}
\text{s.t.}\ & |x| \leq M'
\end{array}
\end{equation}

where $M'<M$.

Suppose $x^{*}$ denotes an optimal solution for the first model, and $x^{'}\neq x^{*}$ denotes the optimal solution to the second model and $x^{'}$ is not optimal for the first model.

Assume $M'$ is not a valid upper bound for $x$ implying $F(x^{'})> F(x^{*})$.

Is it possible that $x^{'}$ be strictly within the feasible region defined by $|x|\leq M'$, or at least one of $x_i$ will hit the $M'$?

Comment: Just for clarification: by $|x|\leq M$ you intend to model $x_1 \leq M, x_2 \leq M, ...,x_n\leq M$ and not $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \leq M$?

Comment: If we assume the problem is strongly convex, i.e. the global minimizer $x_{opt}$ is unique, then yes. Because in that case $x'$ is not the global minimzer (or we would have $x'=x^*=x_{opt}$), so it must lie on the boundary of the box.  If the problem is degenerate then you must be more careful with how you define the optimal solution.

Comment: The first one. I clarified the question. Thanks.

Comment: $x'$ is not an optimal solution to the first model. In other words, F(x')> F(x*). Clarified the question. Thanks.